# Multiple Registration forms (with unique roles)?

Tags: entities, users

I have a scenario where I want users to be able to register via the standard registration form and be assigned a role of "tenant". I also need the ability for site administrators to be able to create either "tenant" roles (with unique fields) or "landlord" roles (with their own unique fields and roles).

I've looked at profile2, user role field, and field permissions as possible modules, but I'm unable to see a way of getting this to work. How can I make certain fields required for one role, but hidden for another?

Comment: Do you want to hide the fields in registration forms ?

Comment: That would be great, but even that's not necessary. I'm stuck now because if I make a field required for one role it's required for both roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [profile2_regpath](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_registration) should help you.